Troubles with solving a Laplace equation
I'm struggling in solving an exercise about the Laplace equation over the domain $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi] \times [0, \pi]$ with the boundary conditions:
$f(\frac{\pi}{2},y)=f(\pi,y)=f(x,\pi)=0$
and
$f(x,0)=g(x)$
$-------------------------------------$
Assuming $f(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ my results are, after imposing the boundary conditions:
$X=\sin(2nx)$ (wich is correct)
and
$Y=C_1e^{2ny}+C_2e^{-2ny}$
and imposing
$f(x,\pi)=0$
$Y(\pi)=C_1e^{2n\pi}+C_2e^{-2n\pi}=0$
which is almost equal to
$2C_{12}\sinh(2n\pi)$ if $C_1=C_2$ but I cant get over this.
The proposed solution is: $Y(y)=\sinh{2n(y − π)}$
I really don't get where it comes from.

Notice that
$$
C_1e^{2n\pi}+C_2e^{-2n\pi}=0 \implies C_2=-C_1e^{4n\pi}, \tag{1}
$$
hence
$$
Y=C_1e^{2ny}-C_1e^{4n\pi-2ny}=C_1e^{2n\pi}\left(e^{2n(y-\pi)}-e^{-2n(y-\pi)}\right)
=C\sinh(2n(y-\pi)). \tag{2}
$$

Im definetly rusty. Thank you.
